# Trying to pause program execution within an if statement (Swing)

Tags: java, swing, timer

I'm trying to pause my program and have been looking at using Thread.Sleep(). After reading about the problems this causes I am trying to implement a Swing Timer. However, it seems that Swing timers fire ActionEvents... I'm only looking to pause program execution and have a JLabel change between the following

```
mPlayerLastRollLabel.setText("Player rolled: ...");

//PAUSE

mPlayerLastRollLabel.setText("Player rolled: " + mFaceNumber);
```

How would I use a Timer in the case below to pause the program where I've marked it:

```
class ClickListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            if (mPlayerTurn && event.getSource() == playerRollButton) {
                mFaceNumber = rollDie();
                mPlayerLastRollLabel.setText("Player rolled: ...");

                **// want to pause here //**

                mPlayerLastRollLabel.setText("Player rolled: " + mFaceNumber);

                if (mFaceNumber != 1) {
                    mSubTotal += mFaceNumber;
                    mPlayerSubtotalLabel.setText("Player's current subtotal: " + mSubTotal);
                }
                else {
                    mSubTotal = 0;
                    mPlayerSubtotalLabel.setText("Player's current subtotal: " + mSubTotal);
                    mPlayerTurn = false;
                    mComputerTurn = true;
                }
            }

            if (mPlayerTurn && event.getSource() == playerEndTurnButton) {
                mPlayerTotalScore += mSubTotal;
                mPlayerCurrentTotalScoreLabel.setText("Player's current total score: " + mPlayerTotalScore);
                mSubTotal = 0;
                System.out.println(mPlayerTotalScore);
                mPlayerTurn = false;
                mComputerTurn = true;
            }

            if (mComputerTurn && event.getSource() == computerRollButton) {
                mFaceNumber = rollDie();

                mComputerLastRollLabel.setText("Computer rolled: " + mFaceNumber);

                if (mFaceNumber != 1)
                    mSubTotal += mFaceNumber;
                else {
                    mSubTotal = 0;
                    mPlayerTurn = true;
                    mComputerTurn = false;
                }
            }

            if (mComputerTurn && event.getSource() == computerEndTurnButton) {
                mComputerTotalScore += mSubTotal;
                mSubTotal = 0;
                System.out.println(mComputerTotalScore);
                mPlayerTurn = true;
                mComputerTurn = false;
            }


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because swing timer is asynchronous. So you have to put second line of your code (and all following logic) into action listener like:

```
mPlayerLastRollLabel.setText("Player rolled: ...");
Timer t = new Timer(5000, new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        mPlayerLastRollLabel.setText("Player rolled: " + mFaceNumber);
    }
});
t.setRepeats(false);
t.start();
```

Or you can put second half after sleep into separate function and call it from actionPerfomed method. Doing it this way instead of Thread.sleep you release graphical thread (which is one for all UI) until your sleeping time is up. If don't release graphical thread then your UI would freeze because there would be no thread to react to user actions.

Comment: Excellent! Do you think the structure of my code is OK? Currently I have one ActionListener handling events from four sources (all buttons)... is this typical of a Swing app or do most people break out a separate ActionListener per button? @rsutormin

Comment: I think it's a matter of taste. Personally I prefer to separate action code using anonymous ActionListener implementations (as I used in my example). The only reason for me to join several action listeners into global one is a need to react the same way to several different events.

Comment: I had a similar problem, but if I don't want to put the remainder of my program into an actionPerformed statement. How can I come back to the main Swing thread AFTER and ONLY AFTER the timer stops? Testing for timer.isRunnable() in the main thread does not work even though timer.stop() is called in actionPerformed.